# integrating a chat module to existing ruby app

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, chat, juggernaut

I have a rails application (Rails3 / ruby 1.9.x), and my client wants a chat to be integrated with the application (Ex: like in 'facebook'), So I would like to know what are my options are and what would be the best approach, following are the requirments

1 - Only the logged in users (to the ruby application) should be able to chat with their friends
2 - a simple chat, (no need to pass images, files etc..)
3 - will not be used heavy (like facebook chat)

Following are the options I think I might have

**1 - create a chat module (Ex: by using [juggernaut](http://juggernaut.rubyforge.org/))**, But my concerns are,

will that be a simple implementation

since 'juggernaut', uses flash will that be a drawback

**2 - Integrate a 3rdparty open source chat module (ruby)**

I'm not sure there are once out there like this.

**3 - Integrate a 3rdparty open source chat module (javascript)**

I'm not sure there are once out there like this.

I'm not sure how to do authentication and all ;(

could u please help me here :)

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you like this, its an ruby messaging gem

https://github.com/ging/mailboxer